# could not load file or assembly 'crystaldecisions.reportappserver.datasetconversion' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm working with an asp.net c# project. My project is running fine from localhost. but when I try to publish the project to IIS, I'm getting this error:

> "could not load file or assembly
> 'crystaldecisions.reportappserver.datasetconversion' or one of its
> dependencies. an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
> format".

I have also added this crystaldecision reference after getting this error, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

i got this problem too

(could not load file or assembly 'crystaldecisions.reportappserver.datasetconversion' or one of its dependencies. an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format),

and solved it by unchecking 'precompile during publishing'.

lost several working hours until discovered hot to get rid of it :(